# Pass radio button value into URL of onClick in form

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I'm needing some help getting the following form working with radio button values.  I want users to select a category (using a `select`drop down) and then a size (using radio buttons) and have both the values of the category and sizes passed into a URL when clicking on a button.  So it would take the user to `http://thewebsiteaddress.com/category/size`.

The basic form I have below works fine except for the radio button value - it keeps showing as 'undefined' in the URL when the button is clicked.  I'm very new to this and would appreciate any help getting me on the right path or showing me a better way of performing this task.

Thanks for any guidance here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function combineSelections(cat,sizes){
location.href='http://thewebsiteaddress.com/product-category/'+cat.value+'/'+sizes.value;
}
</script>
<form name="searchbysize">
<select name="categories">
<option value="">Select Product Category</option>
<option value="category-slug">Category Name</option>
</select>
<input type="radio" id="very-small" name="size" value="very-small" />
<label for="very-small">Very Small </label>

<input type="radio" name="size" value="small" />
<label for="small">Small </label>

<input value="Search for Products" onclick="combineSelections(categories,size)"
type="button"></form>
```

Comment: It is undefined. In `combineSelections(categories,size)`, you haven't defined the variables `categories` and `size`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `id="categories"` to the select and `id="size"` to the radio button and then use `document.getElementById()` to get the values of the radio button and select.

```
function combineSelections()
{
   var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
   var category = document.getElementById('categories').value;
   location.href='http://thewebsiteaddress.com/product-category/'+category+'/'+size;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much - that makes so much more sense now and with the variables properly defined I've finally got it working perfectly.  Appreciate the help.